# Changing DISPLAY value

Tags: ssh, display, x11-forwarding

I have been trying to run some graphics on my local client while I am connected through SSH to another server. Previously `export DISPLAY=:10` would allow xeyes to run on my monitor, but sometimes it doesn't work and the display value needs to be changed to `:11`. I tried both today, and both result in `Error: can't open display`. Can anyone tell me why this keeps happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The value of `DISPLAY` to be set on SSH X-forwarding is usually 10 + (whatever the value is on your local system). So, if locally you have `DISPLAY=:0`, then the forwarded setting will use `DISPLAY=:10`, and `DISPLAY=:1` locally will need `DISPLAY=:11` on the SSH session.
Check the value of `echo $DISPLAY` on a local terminal.

The value of `DISPLAY` locally in turn depends on the number of X11 sessions you have running (actually the value that was given to `X11` when it was executed, but that's usually set by the display manager based on the number of currently running X11 sessions). So if two users are logged in, one will probably have `DISPLAY=:0`, reusing LightDM's X11 session (assuming LightDM is the display manager), and the other will have `DISPLAY=:1`, and if third user also logs in to the GUI, they'll probably get `DISPLAY=:2`, and so on.

---

The value of `10` comes from the offset given to SSH:

```
$ grep X11DisplayOffset /etc/ssh/sshd_config
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that!
I tried that, and when I change my display value to `:10` it runs xeyes, but nothing comes up on the screen.

Comment: So locally you get `:0` for `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: I do get `:0` locally.

(I also use `ssh -y` to connect)

Comment: Do you mean `-Y`? `-y` is for logging and `-Y` is for X11 forwarding

Comment: I used `-y` instead of `-Y` but it has worked in the past. Let me try it with this change.
if I use `-Y` I get this error upon changing my `DISPLAY` value to `:10`

`connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
Error: Can't open display: :10`

Comment: I am not sure your answer is fully correct: in particular, I don't think the remote display number is X11DisplayOffset + the local display number. Two counterexamples: 1) Imagine two user with local display number 0 connecting (with ssh, X11, ...) to the same server. They cannot both get remote display number 10. 2) I observe that while my local display number is 66, the remote is always 10 (or 11, if someone else is already connected).